# How to provide code samples for nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jsfiddle

What is the best way to provide code samples for my NodeJS application that uses mongo via mongoose.

I am dealing with a problem where I want to post a working example of some schemas & models that requires DB access.

I was hoping for something like jsfiddle but could not quite figure out how to use that for what I wanted.

Yes, I'm a noob...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try the reliable service of c9.io?

I haven't tried using Mongoose there, but it shouldn't be much of a magic.

Comment: Yeah, that would be an option I guess.  I use it for some development work, but it's heavier weight than what I was hoping for.  But I'm starting to believe what I want does not exist. ;)